# GitHub "Used By" / Dependents Not Populating

Tags: github, pypi, python-packaging, dependabot, dependency-graph

My project [`pyngrok`](https://github.com/alexdlaird/pyngrok) has hundreds of starts, is listed as a PyPI "Critical Project", and thus is used by many other projects, including significant ones. But the "Used By" section has never populated or show up on my project's GitHub page. Similarly, if I [go in to check on the Dependency Graph](https://github.com/alexdlaird/pyngrok/network/dependents), nothing is ever listed as dependent of `pyngrok`, despite the fact that it's been on pip for years and it definitely has dependents (including [some of my own projects](https://github.com/alexdlaird/hookee). These projects list it in their `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` (and such projects [do show up on Libraries.io](https://libraries.io/pypi/pyngrok), so seems like they're listing dependencies properly).

GitHub's own documentation on how exactly the Dependency Graph works and Used By is populated is [sparse at best](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/understanding-your-software-supply-chain/exploring-the-dependencies-of-a-repository#dependents-view), but from [what they have published](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/understanding-your-software-supply-chain/exploring-the-dependencies-of-a-repository#changing-the-used-by-package), my package meets all the requirements. But I'm wondering if I'm missing an obvious configuration step on my end, since I have the exact same issue on `pyngrok`'s sister Java project [`java-ngrok`](https://github.com/alexdlaird/java-ngrok)—it's less popular, but still definitely has dependents that should be appear. Am I doing something wrong here? I raised a ticket a while back with GitHub, but they never responded, so any direction others could give would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on this, as it is now resolved. I've also seen that many users are reporting the same issue on [this (and other) GitHub Community page(s)](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/34687). Ultimately, though, none of those solutions worked for my Python or Java repos—I opened a GitHub support ticket, and while it took a couple weeks to get a response, their engineers took a look to resolve the issue.

If you're experiencing the same issue, try [opening a ticket with GitHub Support](https://support.github.com/). They didn't explain to me what they did to fix it, simply that their engineers looked at the issue and that it should now be resolved (and it was, but it appears to be some manual process they have to do for each effected repo, so send them a link to yours as well through a ticket).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Dependabot is not always able to work with metadata from `setup.py` files (nor `setup.cfg`). If you place your metadata in `pyproject.toml`, Dependabot should be able to pick up the metadata more reliably. You do not have to put all metadata in `pyproject.toml` (you can keep some in `setup.cfg` or even `setup.py`), but the more the better (for Dependabot and many other reasons). And of course the dependent libraries and tools will have higher chances to get picked up by Dependabot if they list your library as dependency via a `pyproject.toml` file (`requirements.txt` should be okay as well).

Comment: There are definitely repos that use `setup.py` where the "Used By" section still populates ([example](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework)), but I'll try to make this shift since `setup.py` is deprecated and see if it makes a difference. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I see... this is strange indeed. I also had not realized that GitHub lists your project's dependencies but not its dependents. Maybe a bug on their side...

Comment: Indeed. I'll continue the path with the ticket from them, maybe someday I'll get an answer there, and I'll be sure to update the ticket there—also doesn't explain why my `java-ngrok` project, a Java library and not a Python package, has the same issue.